# skip the split if digit follows a string to get an array in python/pyspark

Tags: python, arrays, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

want to create a new column based on a string column that have as separator(" ") and skip the split  if a digit followed  and finally delete ";" in the end if exist using python/pyspark :

Inputs :

```
"511 520 NA 611;"
"322 GA 620"  
"3 321;"
"334344"
```

expected Output :

```
+Column           | +new column
"511 520 NA 611;" | [511,520,NA 611]
"322 GA 620"      | [322,GA 620]
"3 321; "         | [3,321]
"334 344"         | [334,344]
```

try :

```
data = data.withColumn(
"newcolumn",
split(col("column"), "\s"))
```

but i get an empty string at the end of the array like here and i want to delete it if exist

```
+Column        | +new column
"511 520 NA 611;" | [511,520,NA,611;]
"322 GA 620"      | [322,GA,620]
"3 321;"       | [3,321;]
"334 344"      | [334,344]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the commends you can use [regexp_extract_all](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#regexp_extract_all) together with the right regexp as shown below:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
data = [
  ["511 520 NA 611;"],
  ["322 GA 620"],
  ["3 321;"],
  ["334344"]
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["value"]) 

df.withColumn("extracted_value", F.expr("regexp_extract_all(value, '(\\\d+)|(\\\w+\\\s\\\d+)', 0)")).show()

# +---------------+------------------+
# |          value|   extracted_value|
# +---------------+------------------+
# |511 520 NA 611;|[511, 520, NA 611]|
# |     322 GA 620|     [322, GA 620]|
# |         3 321;|          [3, 321]|
# |         334344|          [334344]|
# +---------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp_replace to replace the ";" at the end of the string first, and then execute split.
Regular expression ";$" indicates that match the string ends with ";".

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, col, regexp_replace

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [
    ("511 520 NA 611;",),
    ("322 GA 620",),
    ("3 321;",),
    ("334 344",)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['column'])
df = df.withColumn("newcolumn", split(regexp_replace(col("column"), ';$', ''), "\\s"))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: this works to deal with the ";" at the end but still not skip the split if a digit is followed as i explain in the output expected

Comment: Only think of a more dumb way. First use the regexp_extract_all function to extract all special strings, then perform split on the rest of the strings, and finally concatenate the extracted special strings with the split result. But this cannot guarantee the order.